# Google Sheets app not displaying current date in cell while using =TODAY function

Tags: google-sheets

I have everything set correctly, yet the date is ahead one day. Am currently writing this on Mar 31, 2023 yet the cell says Apr 01 2023.

Trying to figure out why it says this when my device time is for Mar 31 and not Apr 01.

Followed steps according to Google, same erroneous date.

Comment: go to File > Settings and check the timezone of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Again.... This is the Android app

Comment: well, what's the problem? You can still do it. Just open Sheets from your browser with desktop mode enabled. There is no built-in option in the mobile app.

Comment: Can you not read? I'm using the mobile app (which has no desktop option) and the time within the cell that I'm using to display the date is incorrect. It keeps advancing a day before the current day is complete. Now do you get it?

Comment: And when you open in the browser, it takes you to the app. I don't have a PC. It doesn't allow you to make changes from the browser on mobile anymore, they got rid of that years ago and IDK why.

Comment: NVM, figured it out. Have to go to sheets dot google dot com in desktop for it to work. Didn't use to do that. Google messing with what isn't broken. Ugh